# Set outline border on a focused element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My code loads various items on some button click event into the document.
I managed to set the focus properly on the first item from those freshly loaded items once there all have been displayed using the following code:

```
$(function () {
    $("a.getfocus").focus();                            
});
```

This works but **I would also like the browser's default outline to show up on this focused item**.
Is there any easy solution to achieve this ?

Comment: Format, grammar

Comment: Format, grammar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the `:focus` pesudoselector to the element and the `outline` property:

```
outline: [properties]
```

---

Say, you have a link which usually shows an outline on focus (yep, that's the default behaviour):

```
<a id="test" href="https://test.com">Test</a>
```

With CSS, you can do the following:

```
#test {
    outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

to get a red outline. Usually, you'd want to do:

```
a {
    outline: none;
}
```

Back to your question, you can do:

```
a:focus {
    ...
    // rules
    ...
}
```

You can see a small sample [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQPgMw).

Comment: yeah, I tried the Approach your are suggesting but that is not working for me.
here you are suggesting to set outline by using  id  to anchor that also i tried with that getfocus class.but here i also want to remove that outline when that item is loosing focus.

Comment: That was just a simple example. Let me write a small sample for you to check out?

Comment: please,I would be grateful.

Comment: Thank you that is realy helpfull

Comment: No worries! Can we close the question?

Comment: yeah sure,why not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164805/discussion-between-weirdpanda-and-madhav).

Comment: The codepen does not work, at all, neither on Chrome nor Firefox.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of it: https://i.imgur.com/xlQwz0z.png

Comment: There was some context in the chat, but at this stage I honestly do not remember it. That really isn't a reason why you would downvote the response considering this used to be valid around 5 years ago.